# Не удается вытащить значение из базы

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Есть вот такая структура данных
(для примера приведу 3 элемента на самом деле их несколько миллионов)

```
   '6444': [
    { TICKER: 'EURUSD' },
    { DTYYYYMMDD: '20030509' },
    { TIME: '142300' },
    { OPEN: '1.14888' },
    { HIGH: '1.14898' },
    { LOW: '1.14881' },
    { CLOSE: '1.14889' },
    { VOL: '835' }
  ],
  '6445': [
    { TICKER: 'EURUSD' },
    { DTYYYYMMDD: '20030509' },
    { TIME: '142400' },
    { OPEN: '1.14886' },
    { HIGH: '1.14893' },
    { LOW: '1.14874' },
    { CLOSE: '1.14892' },
    { VOL: '889' }
  ],
  '6446': [
    { TICKER: 'EURUSD' },
    { DTYYYYMMDD: '20030509' },
    { TIME: '142500' },
    { OPEN: '1.14886' },
    { HIGH: '1.14904' },
    { LOW: '1.14886' },
    { CLOSE: '1.14904' },
    { VOL: '772' }
  ]
```

Для того что бы вытащить из данной таблицы(`TRADING`) и данной коллекции (`EUR/USD`) хоть какое то значение использую следующий код:

```
await client.connect();
const testingData = client.db('Trading').collection('EUR/USD');
const getSomeCurrencyData = await testingData.findOne({'6446': { VOL: '772' }});
```

Вопросы:

1. Почему данным запросом не удается вытащить значение из базы?
2. Каким запросом можно вытащить хотя бы что нибудь конкретное?
3. Почему используя запрос:

testingData.findOne('6446': [
{ TICKER: 'EURUSD' },
{ DTYYYYMMDD: '20030509' },
{ TIME: '142500' },
{ OPEN: '1.14886' },
{ HIGH: '1.14904' },
{ LOW: '1.14886' },
{ CLOSE: '1.14904' },
{ VOL: '772' }
]);

Я в итоге получаю абсолютно все значения которые существуют в базе, а не только одно конкретное, которое я указал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо сначала указывать _id документа в коллекции 'EUR/USD', затем фильтр...

```js
await client.connect();
const testingData = client.db('Trading').collection('EUR/USD');

const getSomeCurrencyData = await testingData.findOne({_id:'yourId'},{_id:1,'6446':{ $slice: -1 } });//Вернёт поле _id и последний элемент массива 6446 в документе с _id "yourId"

//const getSomeCurrencyData = await testingData.findOne({_id:'yourId'},{'6446': { $elemMatch: { VOL: {$exists: true} }}});//Вернёт элемент массива 6446, в котором есть поле VOL в документе с _id "yourId"
```